# Deep learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

What's the difference between **deep belief network** and **deep convex network**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Deep convex network* is relatively new **architecture** of *deep neural networks*, which has been developed in order to overcome the **scalability** limitations of *deep belief networks (DBN)*. You can read more on *technical details* of the architecture and its *performance* in research papers, for example, in [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/152133/DeepConvexNetwork-Interspeech2011-pub.pdf) as well as a relevant [later paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/164624/5045.pdf), both from Microsoft Research.

It might be beneficial to read more about DBN on [this fascinating peer-reviewed open-access site](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Deep_belief_networks), as it's more comprehensive than Wikipedia on the topic. In my opinion, even more comprehensive and interesting **overview** of *deep learning architectures* in AI can be found in [this technical report](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/TR1312.pdf).

Comment: interesting.....i'll read those papers.....is there any open source implementation for deep convex net?

Comment: @hadooper: Thanks for upvoting, glad you find it helpful. Don't know about the open source implementation, at least backed by Microsoft. I very much doubt it, as Microsoft uses deep learning for highly competitive products, such as Bing and Skype Translator: http://blogs.skype.com/2014/12/15/skype-translator-how-it-works.

Comment: indeed....there is no open source DCN implementation available...!!!

Comment: @hadooper: I was pretty sure of that. However, I am as well pretty sure that it is just a matter of time, until we will see some open source implementations of DCN, similarly to already existing neural networks and deep learning projects.

Comment: Microsoft researchers achieved 0.83% test error rate with DCN and H2o is getting 0.87% error rate with deep learning for same mnist dataset...(SOURCE : http://www.slideshare.net/0xdata/h2-o-deeplearningarnocandel052114)

Comment: @hadooper: Quite interesting. Thanks for the link. I'm aware of H2O, but when I looked at this project, I haven't seen any references to deep learning - either I missed them, or the folks implemented it, moving forward fast.